# What is the difference between ngInclude and ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

I was about to start using ngRoute because the ngRouter is all the talk here lately but I started realizing ngInclude is working fine for me and i'm wondering why everyone seems to be using ngRouter instead.  They both load templates (or fragments) and I can attach a controller to either or.  Is the only benefit to using ngRoute that you can use href to load a template? I don't mind using ng-click and changing a ngInclude value to true.  Seems easier to me but i'm sure i'm missing something.

Comment: these are I think two quite different beasts. You might find some useful guidance [here, doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) or [here, tutorial](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/22/the-basics-of-using-ui-router-with-angularjs/)

Comment: Yes i read about ngRouter but to me it looked very similar to ngInclude at least in how i'd use it.  It's not like the docs tell you the differences between directives and the pros and cons in a single page mobile app verses a browser based app.  I am using angular in a single page mobile app so bookmarks are not an issue and neither is search bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using a router is to assign URLs to pages of your app. So that I can refresh the current page, or send a link to the current page to a friend, or bookmark the current page, and land on **that** page, instead of landing on the home page of the app.

Comment: not to mention SEO. Bots have no way to see content if there aren't links to it